# How to uncheck a checked checkbox on load in Reactjs.Net?

Tags: reactjs.net

I am retrieving a record while a page is being loaded and based on its value I check the checkbox, like:

```
<div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-md-3 ">
  <input type="checkbox" key={item.AttributeID}  checked="checked" name={"Value" + item.AttributeID} className={classs} onClick={() => that.selectCheckBox(value) } />
   <label>{item.AttributeName}</label>
</div>
```

The checkbox is checked and working fine, now on the UI I'm not able to uncheck that checked checkbox:

if (item.IsChecked == true) { subControlAttributesRows.push( that.selectCheckBox(value) } /> {item.AttributeName}); }

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried

Comment: if (item.IsChecked == true) {
                        subControlAttributesRows.push(<div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-md-3 "><input type="checkbox" key={item.AttributeID} checked  name={"Value" + item.AttributeID} className={classs} onClick={() => that.selectCheckBox(value) } /> <label>{item.AttributeName}</label></div>);
                    }

Comment: Do not put code in comment section. Put it in your question